# Why is there space?

Tags: spacing, alignat

Why is there some space between f(pi) f'(pi) and in Z

[image]

[image]

Comment: whar do you expect to happen? You are specifying with `&` the `\in` all align and so there has to be some space somewhere: you do not need  4!! `&` at that point though,

Comment: please always show code as a complete small document in  code block do not post code as an image.

Comment: if you want f(\pi) to right align towrds the `\in` move one `&` from after it to before it

Comment: Clickbait! I hoped for a physics or philosophical discussion but all I got was latex.

Answer (score 7):

I won't claim my mind-reading skills are any good, but I suspect that what you *really* want is something like this -- observe the argument `{2}` instead of `{3}` in `alignat*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(0)          &\in\Z&       f(\pi) &\in\Z \\
f'(0)         &\in\Z&       f'(\pi)&\in\Z \\
\vdots        &     &       \vdots        \\
f^{(2n+1)}(0) &\in\Z&\qquad f^{(2n+1)}(0)(\pi)&\in\Z
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Im new to that alignat thingy and to latex I don't get it sometimes why something is aligned in an other place and when to use & or && or &&&
But thanks